# Jquery chart stopped showing all of a sudden

Tags: jquery, drupal, charts, drupal-webform

I have the following code, which was creating a graph on the confirmation page of my Drupal Webform (I created a stress test), and has been working fine for several weeks.  Now all of a sudden this entirely just stopped working.

http://www.beatinganger.com/node/353/done?sid=720

Anyone have any ideas why it stopped working, and how to get it working again?  I didn't make any changes to the code.  I have been tearing my hair out.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var ticks = [], vals = [];
    var one = $('#edit-submitted-physical-state, #edit-submitted-mental-state, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-belonging, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-justice, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-integrity, #edit-submitted-weight-management, #edit-submitted-emotional-ease, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-stimulation, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-justice, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-relationship, #edit-submitted-feelings-of-satisfaction')
        .each(function(i, el) {
            vals.push(Number(el.value));
            ticks.push($('label[for="'+el.id+'"]').text().replace('Feelings of ', '').replace(': ', '').replace(' State', '').replace(' Ease', '').replace(' Management', '').replace(' Control', ''));
        });

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [vals], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            },
            yaxis: {
            min: 0,
        max: 20, 
        }


        }
    });
});
```

In my head section I have the following

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.beatinganger.com/scripts/jquery.jqplot.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.beatinganger.com/scripts/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.beatinganger.com/scripts/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.beatinganger.com/scripts/jquery.jqplot.css" />
```

Comment: Can you show us how you include jquery.js ?

Comment: Hi Zubair, I have edited my original question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqPlot is expecting an ID, but you're using a class on your page. Try changing it to id="chart1"

Comment: Good spot Mike - I must have changed it by accident and not realised and even thought to look there.  Thanks.

Comment: In your defense, they shouldn't have programmed in such a brittle manner

Answer (score 0):

Got it. May be that server is down or file have been moved. So, save .js file from that server and then use it from local directory.

Comment: oh, but that server is our server that the website runs off?  I have them all in a scripts folder in the root... Very strange.

Comment: I mean server: http://www.beatinganger.com, save your css and .js from this server manually, then put your script in a folder of your project like scripts and link them as src="scripts/jquery.jqplot.js".